# Highcharts label formatter return inside and outside if statement? Is this correct?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Using highcharts label formatter

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.formatter

I'm using the code below to customize the first label, and return the values for all others. Is this how I should use `return` twice within the formatter? While it works i'm just checking that there isn't a better way to write the function. I'm a little new to js and wondering if the returned data could be combined some how?

Thanks

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UvxT2/)

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            marginBottom: 80
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                //align: 'left',
                //x: 0,
                //y: -2,
                useHTML: true,
                formatter:function(){
                    if(this.isFirst){
                        return 'test';
                    }
                    return this.value;
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "if the returned data could be combined some how"? Do you mean like a one-liner? For readability and functionality this looks good to me.

Comment: @Ondkloss I just didn't know I could use return more than once, and was wondering if that was how it should be written.

Comment: Okay, I see. When you say "more than once" you have to realize that once the first `return` occurs, the rest of the code is never executed, since the function has already given it's answer back to the calling code. So it will always be a case of either the first `return` happening or the second one. Never both. That is perfectly fine way to code it.

Comment: @Ondkloss ok to me it seemed as if both were returning data, but in actuality the conditional statement returns only for the first value or `this.isFirst` then the rest of the code executes returning the other values.

Comment: Not getting you ! What do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine. As said @Anagio, only first `return` is executed for first label, for the rest, `if()` is negative, so second `return` is executed.